# Symmetry of Euler-Frobenius coefficient

Tags: summation

The coefficients of an Euler-Frobenius polynomial is given by

$$b_k^n=\sum_{\ell=1}^k(-1)^{k-\ell}\ell^n\left(\begin{matrix}n+1\\k-\ell\end{matrix}\right)$$

The symmetry property of this coefficients say that $b^n_k=b^n_{n+1-k}$

I've tried quite a few things but haven't been able to prove that equality neither find much information about these coefficients. I was looking for ideas that could lead me towards the proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we have the coefficient of the Euler-Frobenius polynomial
$$b_k^n = \sum_{l=1}^k
(-1)^{k-l} l^n {n+1\choose k-l}$$
and we seek to show that $b_k^n = b_{n+1-k}^n$
where $0\le k\le n+1.$

First re-write this as
$$\sum_{l=0}^{k}
(-1)^{l} (k-l)^n {n+1\choose l}.$$

Introduce the Iverson bracket
$$[[0\le l\le k]]
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{z^l}{z^{k+1}} \frac{1}{1-z}
\; dz$$

and the exponentiation integral
$$(k-l)^n =
\frac{n!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{w^{n+1}} \exp((k-l)w) \; dw.$$

to get  for the sum (extend  the summation to $n+1$  since the Iverson
bracket controls the range)

$$\frac{n!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{w^{n+1}} \exp(kw) 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{k+1}} \frac{1}{1-z}
\sum_{l=0}^{n+1} {n+1\choose l} (-1)^l z^l \exp(-lw)
\; dz \; dw
\\ = \frac{n!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{w^{n+1}} \exp(kw) 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{k+1}} \frac{1}{1-z}
(1-z\exp(-w))^{n+1}
\; dz \; dw.$$

Evaluate  this  using  the residues  at  the  poles  at $z=1$  and  at
infinity.

We obtain for $z=1$
$$-\frac{n!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{w^{n+1}} \exp(kw) 
(1-\exp(-w))^{n+1} \; dw,$$

note however  that $1-\exp(-w)$ starts at  $w$ so the  power starts at
$w^{n+1}$ making for a zero contribution.

We get for the residue at infinity
$$-\mathrm{Res}_{z=0} \frac{1}{z^2}
z^{k+1} \frac{1}{1-1/z} 
(1-\exp(-w)/z)^{n+1}
\\ = -\mathrm{Res}_{z=0}
z^{k} \frac{1}{z-1}
(1-\exp(-w)/z)^{n+1}
\\ = \mathrm{Res}_{z=0}
\frac{z^{k}}{z^{n+1}} \frac{1}{1-z}
(z-\exp(-w))^{n+1}.$$

We need to flip the sign on this one more time since we are exploiting
the fact that the residues at the three poles sum to zero.
Actually extracting the coefficient we get
$$-\sum_{q=0}^{n-k} {n+1\choose q} (-1)^{n+1-q} \exp(-(n+1-q)w).$$

Substitute this into the integral in $w$ to get
$$-\sum_{q=0}^{n-k} {n+1\choose q}
\frac{n!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{w^{n+1}} \exp(kw) 
(-1)^{n+1-q} \exp(-(n+1-q)w) \; dw
\\ = -\sum_{q=0}^{n-k} {n+1\choose q}
(-1)^{n+1-q} (-1)^n (n+1-k-q)^n
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^{n-k} {n+1\choose q}
(-1)^q (n+1-k-q)^n.$$

Using the fact that $n+1-k-q$ is zero at $q=n+1-k$ we finally obtain
$$\sum_{q=0}^{n+1-k} {n+1\choose q}
(-1)^q (n+1-k-q)^n$$
which is precisely $b_{n+1-k}^n$ by definition, QED.

**Addendum.**  An  alternate proof  (variation  on  the theme  from
above) starts from the unmodified definition and introduces

$${n+1\choose k-l}
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{k-l+1}} (1+z)^{n+1} \; dz.$$

This controls the range so we may extend $l$ to infinity.
Introduce furthermore
$$l^n =
\frac{n!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{w^{n+1}} \exp(lw) \; dw.$$

These two yield for the sum
$$\frac{n!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{w^{n+1}} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(-1)^k}{z^{k+1}} (1+z)^{n+1} 
\sum_{l\ge 0} (-1)^l z^l \exp(lw)
\; dz \; dw
\\ = \frac{n!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{w^{n+1}} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(-1)^k}{z^{k+1}} (1+z)^{n+1} 
\frac{1}{1+z\exp(w)}
\; dz \; dw
\\ = \frac{n!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{\exp(-w)}{w^{n+1}} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{(-1)^k}{z^{k+1}} (1+z)^{n+1} 
\frac{1}{z+\exp(-w)}
\; dz \; dw.$$

We evaluate this using the  negatives of the residues at $z=-\exp(-w)$
and at infinity. We get for $z=-\exp(-w)$

$$\frac{n!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{\exp(-w)}{w^{n+1}} 
\frac{(-1)^k}{(-1)^{k+1} \exp(-(k+1)w)}
(1-\exp(-w))^{n+1} \; dw
\\ = - \frac{n!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{\exp(kw)}{w^{n+1}} 
(1-\exp(-w))^{n+1} \; dw.$$

As before  the exponentiated term starts  at $w^{n+1}$ so  there is no
coefficient on $w^n$ for a contribution of zero.

We get for the residue  at infinity (starting from the next-to-last
version of the integral)

$$-\mathrm{Res}_{z=0} \frac{1}{z^2}
(-1)^k z^{k+1} \frac{(1+z)^{n+1}}{z^{n+1}} \frac{1}{1+\exp(w)/z}
\\ = -\mathrm{Res}_{z=0} \frac{1}{z^2}
(-1)^k z^{k+1} \frac{(1+z)^{n+1}}{z^{n+1}} \frac{z/\exp(w)}{1+z/\exp(w)}
\\ = -\mathrm{Res}_{z=0}
(-1)^k z^{k} \frac{(1+z)^{n+1}}{z^{n+1}} \frac{\exp(-w)}{1+z/\exp(w)}.$$

Doing the sign flip and simplifying we obtain
$$\exp(-w) (-1)^k \times \mathrm{Res}_{z=0}
\frac{(1+z)^{n+1}}{z^{n-k+1}} \frac{1}{1+z/\exp(w)}.$$

Extract the residue to get
$$\exp(-w) (-1)^k 
\sum_{q=0}^{n-k} {n+1\choose q} (-1)^{n-k-q} \exp(-(n-k-q)w)$$

Substitute into the integral in $w$ to obtain
$$\sum_{q=0}^{n-k} {n+1\choose q} \frac{n!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{w^{n+1}}
(-1)^{n-q} \exp(-(n+1-k-q)w) \; dw
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^{n-k} {n+1\choose q} 
(-1)^{n-q} (-1)^{n}
(n+1-k-q)^n
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^{n-k} 
 {n+1\choose q} (-1)^q (n+1-k-q)^n.$$

We have obtained $b_{n+1-k}^n$ as before.