# Prove a summation equals to one

Tags: real-analysis

How to prove that
$$
S = \sum_{k=0}^{K-1} \binom{k+K-1}{K-1} \frac{a^k b^K + a^K b^k}{(a+b)^{k+K}} \mathop{=}\limits^{?} 1,
$$
For $K=2$, I have S = $\frac{a^2+b^2}{(a+b)^2} + \frac{2ab(a+b)}{(a+b)^3}$, which can be boiled down as $S = \frac{(a+b)(a^2+b^2+2ab)}{(a+b)^3} = 1$.

Also, WolframAlpha gave the result
$$
S = 2 - \binom{2K-1}{K-1} \frac{(xy)^K}{(x+y)^{2K}} \left\{ {}_2F_1\left(1,2K;K+1;\frac{a}{a+b} \right) + {}_2F_1\left(1,2K;K+1;\frac{b}{a+b} \right) \right\},
$$
but $S = 1$ only when $0 < \frac{a}{a+b} < 1$ and $0 < \frac{b}{a+b} < 1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write $x={a\over a+b},\ J=K-1$, and 
$$f(x,J) = (1-x)^{J+1}\sum_{k=0}^J{J+k\choose k}x^k$$ Then we want to show $$f(x,J)+f(1-x,J)=1,\ J=0,1,2,\dots\tag{1}$$

We proceed by induction on $J$.  When $J=0$, $(1)$ says $x+(1-x)=1.$

Suppose that $J>0$ and that $(1)$ is true for $J-1$.  Then
$$\begin{align}
f(x,J)&=(1-x)^{J+1}\sum_{k=0}^J{J-1+k\choose k}x^k+(1-x)^{J+1}\sum_{k=0}^J{J-1+k\choose k-1}x^k\tag{2}
\end{align}$$
The first term on the right of $(2)$ is $$
(1-x)^{J+1}\sum_{k=0}^{J-1}{J-1+k\choose k}x^k+(1-x)^{J+1}{2J-1\choose J}x^J$$ or
$$(1-x)f(x,J-1)+(1-x)^{J+1}x^J{2J-1\choose J}\tag{3}$$ 
The second term on the right of $(2)$ is 
$$\begin{align}
(1-x)^{J+1}\sum_{k=1}^J {J-1+k\choose k-1}x^k&=(1-x)^{J+1}\sum_{k=0}^{J-1}{J+k\choose k}x^{k+1}\\
&=xf(x,J)-(1-x)^{J+1}{2J\choose J}x^{J+1}\tag{4}
\end{align}$$
Now $(2),(3),\text{ and }(4)$ give

$
(1-x)f(x,J)=(1-x)f(x,J-1)+(1-x)^{J+1}x^J{2J-1\choose J}-(1-x)^{J+1}{2J\choose J}x^{J+1}\tag{6}
$

By symmetry,

$
xf(1-x,J)=xf(1-x,J-1)+x^{J+1}(1-x)^J{2J-1\choose J}-x^{J+1}{2J\choose J}(1-x)^{J+1}\tag{7}
$

Multiply $(6)$ by $x$, multiply $(7)$ by $1-x$, add the results and apply the induction hypothesis to get
$$
x(1-x)(f(x,J)+f(1-x,J))= x(1-x)\tag{8}$$  after verifying that $${2J\choose J}=2{2J-1\choose J}$$

This proves $(2)$ for $x\neq0,1$, but since it is a polynomial identity, it is true for these values also.

Comment: Just a brief query, do you understand the downvote I received?

Comment: @MarkoRiedel No, I was wondering about that that myself.  I haven't upvoted it yet, because I haven't finished reading it.  (I'm still looking for typos in my answer, so I've only had a chance to skim yours.)

Comment: Thank you for this answer, the idea of using induction hypothesis is so simple, I upvoted this post anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from

$$S = \sum_{q=0}^{K-1} {K-1+q\choose K-1}
\frac{a^q b^K + a^K b^q}{(a+b)^{q+K}}$$

we get two pieces

$$\frac{b^K}{(a+b)^K}
\sum_{q=0}^{K-1} {K-1+q\choose K-1} \frac{a^q}{(a+b)^q}
\\ + \frac{a^K}{(a+b)^K}
\sum_{q=0}^{K-1} {K-1+q\choose K-1} \frac{b^q}{(a+b)^q}.$$

This is

$$\frac{b^K}{(a+b)^K} 
[z^{K-1}] \frac{1}{1-z} \frac{1}{(1-az/(a+b))^K}
\\ + \frac{a^K}{(a+b)^K} 
[z^{K-1}] \frac{1}{1-z} \frac{1}{(1-bz/(a+b))^K}.$$

Call these $S_1$ and $S_2.$ The first sum is

$$S_1 = \frac{b^K}{(a+b)^K} 
\mathrm{Res}_{z=0} \frac{1}{z^K} \frac{1}{1-z}
\frac{1}{(1-az/(a+b))^K}
\\ = b^K
\mathrm{Res}_{z=0} \frac{1}{z^K} \frac{1}{1-z}
\frac{1}{(a+b-az)^K}
\\ = \frac{b^K}{a^K}
\mathrm{Res}_{z=0} \frac{1}{z^K} \frac{1}{1-z}
\frac{1}{((a+b)/a-z)^K}
\\ = (-1)^{K+1} \frac{b^K}{a^K}
\mathrm{Res}_{z=0} \frac{1}{z^K} \frac{1}{z-1}
\frac{1}{(z-(a+b)/a)^K}.$$

Now residues sum to zero so we compute this from the residues
at the poles at $z=1$ and $z=(a+b)/a.$ The residue at infinity
is zero by inspection. The residue at $z=1$ is

$$(-1)^{K+1} \frac{b^K}{a^K} \frac{1}{(1-(a+b)/a)^K}
= (-1)^{K+1} b^K  \frac{1}{(a-(a+b))^K}
\\ = (-1)^{K+1}  b^K  \frac{1}{(-b)^K} = -1.$$

For the residue at $z=(a+b)/a$ we require

$$\frac{1}{(K-1)!}
\left(\frac{1}{z^K} \frac{1}{z-1} \right)^{(K-1)}
\\ = \frac{1}{(K-1)!}
\sum_{q=0}^{K-1} {K-1\choose q} 
(-1)^q \frac{(K-1+q)!}{(K-1)!} \frac{1}{z^{K+q}}
(-1)^{K-1-q} \frac{(K-1-q)!}{(z-1)^{K-q}}
\\ = (-1)^{K+1} \sum_{q=0}^{K-1}
{K-1+q\choose K-1} \frac{1}{z^{K+q}}
\frac{1}{(z-1)^{K-q}}.$$

Evaluating the residue we find

$$\left. (-1)^{K+1} \frac{b^K}{a^K}
(-1)^{K+1} \sum_{q=0}^{K-1}
{K-1+q\choose K-1} \frac{1}{z^{K+q}}
\frac{1}{(z-1)^{K-q}} \right|_{z=(a+b)/a}
\\ = \frac{b^K}{a^K}
\sum_{q=0}^{K-1}
{K-1+q\choose K-1} \frac{a^{K+q}}{(a+b)^{K+q}}
\frac{1}{((a+b)/a-1)^{K-q}}
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^{K-1}
{K-1+q\choose K-1} \frac{a^{K+q}}{(a+b)^{K+q}}
\frac{b^q}{a^q}
\frac{b^{K-q}}{a^{K-q}}\frac{1}{((a+b)/a-1)^{K-q}}
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^{K-1}
{K-1+q\choose K-1} \frac{a^{K+q}}{(a+b)^{K+q}}
\frac{b^q}{a^q}
\\ = \frac{a^K}{(a+b)^K} \sum_{q=0}^{K-1}
{K-1+q\choose K-1} \frac{b^q}{(a+b)^{q}} = S_2.$$

We recognise $S_2$ and hence we have shown that

$$S_1-1+S_2 = 0$$

or

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\sum_{q=0}^{K-1} {K-1+q\choose K-1}
\frac{a^q b^K + a^K b^q}{(a+b)^{q+K}} = 1}$$

as claimed.

**Addendum.** This is a special case with $x=a/(a+b)$ of the identity at this [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538309/).

Comment: What theorem are you referring to when you say "residues sum to zero"?  Can you give a link to proof?  I remember that for a rational function ${p(z)\over q(z)}$ with $\deg q -\deg p\geq2$ the sum of the residues is $0$, but then you wouldn't be mentioning $\infty.$   (Of course the result I remember is sufficient in this case, and it's easy to prove.)

Comment: The rational example that you cite also includes the residue at infinity which is zero in your case.  I simply use the generic version, where we have a circular contour going to infinity and eventually enclosing all isolated singularities of a holomorphic function. So you are using that residue as well, even though it is encapsulated in the zero value and not specified explicitly. There is a proof at this [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1984959/).

Comment: When we use the circular contour the contribution from the residue at infinity becomes a requirement, as can be seen at the following two links, [MSE link I](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2109493/) and [MSE link II](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1435648/). Also consult [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Inside-OutsideTheorem.html).

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be proven:
$$S = \sum_{k=0}^{K-1} \binom{k+K-1}{K-1} \frac{a^k b^K + a^K b^k}{(a+b)^{k+K}} \mathop{=}\limits^{?} 1$$
For $K=2$:
$$S = {1\choose 1}\frac{b^2+a^2}{(a+b)^2}+{2\choose 1}\frac{ab^2+a^2b}{(a+b)^3}=\\
\frac{1}{(a+b)^3}\left[{1\choose 1}(b^2+a^2)\color{blue}{(a+b)}+\color{green}{2\choose 1}(ab^2+a^2b)\right]=\\
\frac{1}{(a+b)^3}\left[a^3+\left[\color{blue}{1\choose 1}+\color{green}{2\choose 1}\right](a^2b+ab^2)+b^3\right]=1$$
Note: $1={1\choose 0}={1\choose 1}={3\choose 0}={3\choose 3}, {1\choose 1}+{2\choose 1}={3\choose 1}$.

For $K=3$:
$$S = {2\choose 2}\frac{b^3+a^3}{(a+b)^3}+{3\choose 2}\frac{ab^3+a^3b}{(a+b)^4}+{4\choose 2}\frac{a^2b^3+a^3b^2}{(a+b)^5}=\\
\frac1{(a+b)^5}\left[{2\choose 2}(b^3+a^3)\color{blue}{(a+b)^2}+\color{red}{{3\choose 2}}(ab^3+a^3b)\color{green}{(a+b)}+\color{brown}{4\choose 2}(a^2b^3+a^3b^2)\right]=\\
\frac1{(a+b)^5}\left[a^5+b^5+\left[\color{blue}{{2\choose 1}}+\color{red}{{3\choose 2}}\color{green}{1\choose 0}\right](a^4b+ab^4)+\left[\color{blue}{2\choose 2}+\color{red}{3\choose 2}\color{green}{1\choose 1}+\color{brown}{4\choose 2}\right](a^3b^2+a^2b^3)\right]=1.$$
For $K=4$:
$$S = {3\choose 3}\frac{b^4+a^4}{(a+b)^4}+{4\choose 3}\frac{ab^4+a^4b}{(a+b)^5}+{5\choose 4}\frac{a^2b^4+a^4b^2}{(a+b)^6}+{6\choose 3}\frac{a^3b^4+a^4b^3}{(a+b)^7}=\\
\frac1{(a+b)^7}\left[{3\choose 3}(b^4+a^4)\color{blue}{(a+b)^3}+\color{red}{{4\choose 3}}(ab^4+a^4b)\color{green}{(a+b)^2}+\color{purple}{{5\choose 3}}(a^2b^4+a^4b^2)\color{brown}{(a+b)}+\color{brown}{{6\choose 3}}(a^3b^4+a^4b^3)\right]=\\
\frac1{(a+b)^7}\left[a^7+b^7+\left[\color{blue}{{3\choose 1}}+\color{red}{{4\choose 3}}\color{green}{2\choose 0}\right](a^6b+ab^6)+\left[\color{blue}{{3\choose 2}}+\color{red}{{4\choose 3}}\color{green}{{2\choose 1}}+\color{purple}{{5\choose 3}}\right](a^5b^2+a^2b^5)+\left[\color{blue}{3\choose 0}+\color{red}{{4\choose 3}}\color{green}{2\choose 0}+\color{purple}{5\choose 3}\color{brown}{1\choose 0}+\color{brown}{{6\choose 3}}\right](a^4b^3+a^3b^4)\right]=1.$$
The sums of binomials should be calculated by closed form, which I will leave to you.